# Como instanciar um Objeto em C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, lista, unity3d, objetos

Como faço para instanciar um Objeto em outra classe?

Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
        GameObject Cozinha = new GameObject("CenaCozinha");
        CenaCozinha coz = Cozinha.AddComponent<CenaCozinha>();
```

Mas acredito que assim ele esta criando um novo Objeto, daí tudo que ja coloquei no 'Cozinha' original(como alimentar listas por exemplo), não vai existir no novo.

Comment: Você deve passar a instancia do objeto criada por uma função e salvar em uma propriedade na sua nova classe.

Comment: hum, pode exemplificar pfvr?

Comment: Postarei uma resposta!

Comment: Ok, obrigado :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve passar a instancia do objeto criada por uma função e salvar em uma propriedade na sua nova classe.
Exemplo:

Primeiro crie uma classe que tenha uma propriedade com o tipo de classe desejado:

```
public class NewClass
{
    private GameObject _object;
    public void SetObject(GameObject obj)
    {
        _object = obj;
    }
}
```

Após isso, instancie a nova classe e passe o objeto pelo void criado

```
GameObject Cozinha = new GameObject("CenaCozinha");
CenaCozinha coz = Cozinha.AddComponent<CenaCozinha>();

NewClass newClass = new NewClass();
newClass.SetObject(coz);
```

Comment: Calma, deixa eu entender, a minha Classe CenaCozinha não sera alterada, todo esse codigo ira na NewClass (que no meu caso aqui é Alimentos)...?

Comment: Você não deixou claro na pergunta qual classe é a principal.
NewClass seria a classe onde você quer reutilizar a instância do CenaCozinha.
Você deve instanciar pelo menos uma vez.

Comment: Vou colocar minhas classes como resposta

Comment: Pronto, esta acima

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você tem a classe CenaCozinha que instancia a classe Alimentos, certo?
Então você deve colocar uma propriedade em Alimentos com o tipo CenaCozinha e atribuir o valor dele na hora que está instanciando,

Exemplo:
`public CenaCozinha Cena;`

`novoAlimento.Cena = this;`

Comment: Ae cara! Deu Certo! Obrigadão! ;D

Answer (score 0):

Aqui:

```
public class CenaCozinha : MonoBehaviour { 
//Os Alimentos
public GameObject Alimento;
public GameObject Agua;

public List<Alimentos> alimentosCozinha = new List<Alimentos>();    

void Start () {
}

void Update () {
    foreach (Alimentos al in alimentosCozinha) {
        if (al.nomeAlimento == "agua" && al.quantidade > 0 && !Agua.activeSelf) {
            al.meshAlimento.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

public void ComprarAgua() {
    foreach (Alimentos al in alimentosCozinha) {
        if (al.nomeAlimento == "agua"){
            al.quantidade++;
            return;
        }
    }
    Alimentos novoAlimento = Alimento.AddComponent<Alimentos>();
    novoAlimento.id = "agua";
    novoAlimento.nomeAlimento = "agua";
    novoAlimento.quantidade = 1;
    novoAlimento.meshAlimento = Agua;
    alimentosCozinha.Add(novoAlimento); 
}}
```

E

```
public class Alimentos : MonoBehaviour { public string id;
public int quantidade;
public string nomeAlimento;
public GameObject meshAlimento;
public string id;

public void Start () {
}

public void Update () {
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisao) {
    if (!colisao.gameObject.CompareTag("Agua")) {
        GameObject Cozinha = new GameObject("CenaCozinha");
        CenaCozinha coz = Cozinha.AddComponent<CenaCozinha>();
        Debug.Log(coz.Alimento);
        Debug.Log(coz.Agua);
        foreach (Alimentos al in coz.alimentosCozinha) {
            Debug.Log(Cozinha);
        }
    }
}}
```

Em Debug.Log(coz.Alimento); Debug.Log(coz.Agua); Ele me retorna Null.